# Find the number of points of differentiability for the following function.

Tags: calculus, continuity

If 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
    \cos x^3&;x\lt0\\
    \sin x^3 - |x^3-1|&;x\ge0
\end{cases}$$

then find the number of points where $g(x)=f(|x|) \text { is non differentiable.}$

Comment: I was able to find out one point. The given function is not differentiable at x=1. which may be other point(s?)

Comment: I solved it by graph and i was able to find only one point. But answer is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is asking about $f(|x|)$, by symmetry, since $g(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=1$, it is not differentiable at $x=-1$ as well.

To show that it is not differentiable at $x=1$:

If it is differentiable at $x=1$, then the following limit exists.
\begin{align}\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}&= \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{\sin x^3 - \sin 1-|x^3-1|}{x-1}\end{align}

since $\sin x^3$ is differentiable everywhre, the limit exists if and only if the following limit exists.

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{|x^3-1|}{x-1}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} sign(x-1)|x^2+x+1|=\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}3sign(x-1)$$

Since $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+} sign(x-1) = 1 \neq -1 = \lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-} sign(x-1)$

The function is not differentiable at $x=1$.

Also, we have to verify that the function is differentiable at $x=0$.

$$f(|x|) = \begin{cases} \sin x^3-|x^3-1| & x \geq 0 \\ -\sin x^3 -|x^3+1| & x<0\end{cases}$$

When $|x|<1$,

$$f(|x|) = \begin{cases} \sin x^3-1+x^3 & 0 < x < 1 \\ -\sin x^3 -x^3-1 & -1<x<0\end{cases}$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(|x|)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{sign(x)(\sin x^3+x^3)}{x}=0$$

Comment: You seem to have the wrong definition of $f$. It equals $\cos x^3$ for $x<0.$

Comment: ah, I actually made the mistake as you earlier, the question is asking about $g(x)=f(|x|)$. so we can ignore definition of $f$ when $x<0$.

Comment: Ok, I actually made a mistake in the first line of my answer just now. thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: You're right I did make that mistake. Thanks.